# Avoid WM_MOUSELEAVE when the cursor moves over a child window

Tags: c++, winapi

I am handling mouse hover/leave events with `TrackMouseEvent`, `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` just fine.

The only problem is that when the mouse is hovering over any of the window's children it sends the window that is tracking the mouse a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message.

I actually understand why Windows is doing that, but have no idea how to fix it. Googling didn't help me. I believe the solution is pretty simple and I have just missed something. I am developing Visual C++ Win32 application. (No MFC and so on)

My code:

```
void TrackMouse(HWND hwnd)
{
    TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
    tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
    tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
    tme.dwHoverTime = 1; //How long the mouse has to be in the window to trigger a hover event.
    tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
    TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
}
```

**WndProc:**

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    if (!isTracking)
    {
        TrackMouse(hWnd);
        isTracking = true;
    }
    break;
}
case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    ShowWindow(MouseIsOver, TRUE);
    break;
case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    ShowWindow(MouseIsOver, FALSE);
    isTracking = false;
    break;
```

## Analogy

Think of it this way:

- I want a notification when the mouse **enters** the house
- And i want a notifification when the mouse **leaves** the house

[image]

The mouse hasn't left the house just because it entered the `Bathroom`. And we know (Windows knows) that **House** is the `hwndOwner` of **Bathroom**; so it can guarantee:

- that by entering the `Bathroom`
- that it hasn't left the `House`

Or, put it another way:

- the mouse hasn't **WM_MouseLeft** the `hwndOnwer` control
- simply because the mouse entered an child control

Comment: You should read about [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ReleaseCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

OK, so, on the basis that the OP (probably) wants to, in effect, ignore `WM_MOUSELEAVE` when the cursor passes over a child window of the window tracking the mouse, I think he is probably now doing something like this:

```
BOOL DidMouseLeaveWindow (HWND hWnd)
{
    DWORD msgpos = GetMessagePos ();
    POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM (msgpos), GET_Y_LPARAM (msgpos) };
    ScreenToClient (hWnd, &pt);
    RECT cr;
    GetClientRect (hWnd, &cr);
    return !PtInRect (&cr, pt);
}
```

which seems just fine to me.

If you don't like that for whatever reason, you could also do:

```
BOOL DidMouseLeaveWindow (HWND hWnd)
{
    DWORD msgpos = GetMessagePos ();
    POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM (msgpos), GET_Y_LPARAM (msgpos) };
    HWND hWndUnderCursor = WindowFromPoint (pt);
    return !IsChild (hWnd, hWndUnderCursor);
}
```

which is perhaps a bit more elegant.

There are a couple of issues with both of these approaches though.  If (say) the right-hand edge of a child window aligns exactly with the right-hand edge of the parent and you exit via that edge then the parent will never get its `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.  You might also possibly miss one if you position the cursor over a child window and then move it out of the parent very quickly,

To solve these issues, I would recommend setting up a timer as a backstop.  So, you would do something like:

```
void TrackMouse(HWND hwnd)
{
    // ...
    SetTimer (hWnd, 1, 250, 0);
}
```

And in the WndProc:

```
case WM_TIMER:
case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    if (DidMouseLeaveWindow (hWnd))
    {
        // ...
        isTracking = false;
        KillTimer (hWnd, 1);
    }
    break;
```

It would be nice if `TrackMouseEvent` had a `TME_IGNORE_CHILDREN` flag, but sadly it doesn't.

Comment: I hoped for solution like secret `TME_IGNORE_CHILDREN` flag I just didn't know. The solution with checking coords I have suggested above. Anyway thanks for the few helpful notes about this solution.

Comment: @Grigory, yes perhaps MS missed a trick there. Edited my answer slightly (changed one word).

Answer (score 3):

Your message handler gets a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message to tell it that tracking is done. You have to call `TrackMouseEvent()` again to continue tracking. There's nothing to fix. Your message handler can act accordingly.

Without that message your program would have no knowledge about the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by getting mouse's coords on mouse leave event. The solution is not as beauty as I wanted.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the fact that the parent gets a `WM_MOUSELEAVE` when the mouse passes over a child window, and he doesn't want that. OP please confirm and I will edit your post.

Comment: Exactly so. I thought it's clear after first three sentences.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, I just wanted to be certain.  I will edit for clarity, hope you don't mind (I'll give you a few minutes to respond before I do so).

Comment: The clarity in questions and answers is main purpose of the site. Of course I don't mind.